# Como Inserir em um Banco SQL uma quantidade indeterminada de usuários?

Tags: php, mysql

Olá pessoal sou iniciante em PHP e SQL, preciso fazer uma espécie de formulário que a pessoa informa quantas pessoas quer cadastrar, alguém tem alguma ideia? eu só consigo fazer isso com uma quantidade fixa de variáveis

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se você quer que quando a pessoa preencha ela crie uma nova tabela com campos específicos vc faz:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

// aqui você passa como a pessoa quer, no formulário ela precisará dizer se os dados são do texto, numeros, etc. Aí você separa cada dado, os tipos você envia num array para o post 'tipos', e o nome vc envia para os 'dados'. Na hora do envio você faz as variáveis a baixo um array ou então manda os dados com um separador: Ex  INT(5), VARCHAR(50),...  nesse ex o separador é a ','

$tipos = $_POST['tipos'];
$dados = $_POST['dados'];

//Dentro no '/ /' fica o separador que irá quebrar, no caso está o espaço em 
branco.
$tiposArray = preg_split('/ /', $tipos, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$dadosArray = preg_split('/ /', $dados, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

//Definindo a query
$textoDaQuery;

for (int i = 0; i < count($tiposArray); i++) {
     $textoDaQuery += $dadosArray[i] + $tiposArray[i] + ",";
}

// então você faz:
// Ex de do $textoDaQuery:  nome VARCHAR(50), nascimento DATE
$query = "CREATE TABLE $nomedatabela($textoDaQuery)";

$mysqli->query($query);
```

Assim você cria a tabela para o cliente com os campos e tipos que ele definiu

Comment: Acho que foi isso que você quis fazer, caso não seja, responde aqui que edito a resposta

Comment: Consegui! Muito obg Woton Sampaio, vou postar aqui da forma que eu fiz.

Comment: procurando a forma de posta o código aqui

Comment: @L.Diego fico feliz que conseguiu, se a resposta foi útil, marque como aceita, assim outros que tiverem o msm problema que você poderão resolver seus problemas tb